# How to verify MLSAG sign with a real transaction

Tags: ring-signatures

I'd like to verify a MLSAG signature with a real transaction but it doesn't work..

I chose a transaction `886687fdd30ad46ef1f7c7c18402d82212b4ae1fd2cf6b4dfc549e46be7e22f6`

And here is the code written with mininero

```
import MiniNero

def MLSAG_Ver(msg, pk, n, m, m1, I, c0, s):
    c = c0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        tohash = msg
        j = 0
        while j < m:
            tohash = tohash + pk[j][i]
            L = MiniNero.addKeys(MiniNero.scalarmultBase(s[j][i]), MiniNero.scalarmultKey(pk[j][i], c))
            tohash = tohash + L
            if j < m1:
                HP = MiniNero.hashToPointCN(pk[j][i])
                R = MiniNero.addKeys(MiniNero.scalarmultKey(HP, s[j][i]), MiniNero.scalarmultKey(I, c))
                tohash = tohash + R
            j = j+1
        c = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(tohash)
        i = i+1
    if c == c0:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

msg = "1d990b4638ef747f8ec8a1fa3507eec0c32ceffb3d8e650bcddebe97245469fd"
I = "3352ef16ca15e8cbc67cd1ddd66ae3dc8ea904ab19db9a29de287a5d948b152e"
pk = ["b7abbe863058eb4ed373feae10cfb372848bbe9511fdf4ffaaf69a512482d296",\
      "e926338f8a94751cd38a7c2c70a8b4c6b213eae28efb97cac686c7ef394be396",\
      "e92043567e7e0a6bd942bd765578c132174f496b21c78823a16be6e57e24aaeb",\
      "0377caa3292617487ba32d5a748750eebcca55ad8ac85e06bc772d32354f63af",\
      "a4792780889e5e55bffe1524dcf965d1908d198b5fe698ba7840869c0ecdd6df",\
      "7e684049c73626fa4704a43ace24dc3f1cd467bc22e22cbeba78659f36d14bc9",\
      "177ce3b8bb9c9e0475c6eb5500771cd828b36b1baab0e0eb46abc84ee811bc36",\
      "730e3a22f72b5c2724e822d92332ffd2c2803fba8ba50b5f46a645e719efdc50",\
      "7eb748799bfd30c60214f23ccc4e01b107b10c74435190410ce01aadd46b33e0",\
      "397dce6fadb5b8e37c80340f8a1eea01d2e794cf6faa806e160fa52f991a3bdb",\
      "757be6485a7b4370ac062389ae15b1b46d19b38dcadfde38436fb7c1ce056d59"],\
     ["fd2eca4d0506d9111359add3448be42ba6dbe28d732b5bc3a42cbd5613caaf13",\
      "71929d17d1863471663c7febdf3bace7cc9d366a9bfd1345c2cac43c35d68f8e",\
      "d450e032ba466dd0fadbe831ee5e91187711b37fa4f3c124629066b152ca599b",\
      "2aa4ac5a7d30e375af9153955b510dc3939dd8ceaf58992595356f663469fdac",\
      "7d0d91712e3ddc33c2fd92ce7216b319b3acb1b16aa8147976517e64b4158b67",\
      "4a0acfbe0a869589e66616681e93b9c311b6374d0873541295bc0a8437565376",\
      "e5990b5701085aec19c11d19edd8abf670ad1e53a77b4f0e82d142efdbfb28a0",\
      "75eb46a7b72b2f394d647d6c3b3de290f39238bf3034a381024d6b938e95ba97",\
      "4b4eb4b434f85102c728fe9134feec6cebfbefff881fa673feefc62d02527516",\
      "132cead5678f1902066ee4169de0d94b957360ec4d1e92340907c44a3d5440ad",\
      "cd334425475a8bc219a71c94c0c4b8e277cba0791fb545222dd5fe18e99e6712"]


s =  ["a3628fda5306c2c91986c05e0c939acb1c498c47276863c6b8b4b14381455d05",\
      "4f84565268d4cadd909f626bc85325d968364e5044de9decead91ecb824be60f",\
      "4cd282c891ac453902b0c7cf13a02bbcf328ff8ac4d2fafb20bbb0b67860db07",\
      "9a6e3526b4f28c448c830494e3f98cd0831351a1e5289a3f5c8363687d728206",\
      "733759bb10fc8e228b7ca8b257852418e31ba9b82488355f1fdb2abc9193f90e",\
      "1ece317df2d04b0c783740776362c2ba3c2d5a30fd63852b60d8d535cd92c701",\
      "405b4e3ce3e41be8e36d1d52b64d34a69d5f8eb0aff311202ee41c1cb3787508",\
      "aa2946443c0b2549da165eacd208d84e966e91db8cab27e5b07ec401580ed000",\
      "3ae2b18ce171311c711678d5829ebea65457b52ed7c6085c40782f0c9d8a380b",\
      "e93cf157e4d7c4505b249042a4ae7687354ffb815bf4d53717ea0678daee3407",\
      "b1c559a9140b090217905288ce8f16a961baed949102ad860afb9622259dd600"],\
     ["24a21c6d227540074830b7b4757fc086aba6d5c93babb913e37994f3fb6bb909",\
      "dd50708d2791d39a68caffb22fc99f5b663bf7df0f317913070e08150a0c830d",\
      "bf0d9a648c1c24530e1c9f1c3475b04a3f73de8ce8bc31904bd183da7fd1170e",\
      "13e3a1ced79931086e1682c446af97c58a2604e21df647869f1bb88919e5d602",\
      "df5816a00c64b3a1eced8ad30a1820b4785aaf6c10ff44dfbc71153ab2eb940e",\
      "7ae078de9bc0fe585c4d80ba8ebfea941c6a3a56105b4a6244737b9d0d0ced0e",\
      "a7d589bffc68febe0cbc59c56be34accc1c6847770480ca08a2826b611b9de02",\
      "bc09262d136f22a7c2af6c6a174283bb2f3c398838305f4934b3ea0a05083d0b",\
      "80e21b02139f40d5cc834ca3130a211141aca1a824ce073f26d82a72cafcae07",\
      "14550c61a8111d6a8e9def65195747d406c276e9f4f26b590e02b7b29278150d",\
      "35fc89f428f536dcd2264c9918f29bafa08d9f583b97593229ac8bf4befb7100"]

c0 = "0c7b9e033d4846dbee0d5bb9587d380ee0ae9f635e6376d37fa6f66c94ec3505"

MLSAG_Ver(msg, pk, 11, 2, 1, I, c0, s)
```

I get commitment manually and get msg from formula:

```
m = H(H(tx_prefix), H(ss), H(range proofs))
```

Please help to point out any problem on it.. Many thanks!

I am so sorry for posting this long-winded question... But I am stuck here for a long time..

Here is how I generate msg:

```
import MiniNero

L = "02000102000bda97ba08a9d6019dcd0194fa01ec458a0ce803bb01d202a401b2263352ef16ca15e8cbc67cd1ddd66ae3dc8ea904ab19db9a29de287a5d948b152e0200026ae6652253f1c77e93410f85bf0e495b306d2e5f4f2297ee4b4fc10fe871435c00028d703e7041838d747e5634b7ca6b990720c57f93e65f7f266b05e0dad6ca8b912c01ad79af52c10613be3b4a9a71bd2e8b92cdfa5fa2f548ba985fdd8385bb30947f020901d79d2e801fa7c27a"
M = "049091a309fed5f2ae3250548eb60f5f3eb89676f186063e218c62711ff1991d89b3adb9824a26f3ee8e1c0e5ecbebf2951fb90b7d90716d8a6edc1bfdfba054fa5576d086056a7f3036956468e22148f0522fd6d4"
R = "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"

L1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(L)
M1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(M)
R1 = MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(R)

print(MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(L1+M1+R1))
```

L1 = H(tx_prefix) -> including version, unlock_time, vin, vout, extra.
M1 = H(ss) -> rct_signatures part.
R1 = H(range_proofs) -> rctsig_prunable part.

Comment: There is no guarantee the message formula is 100% accurate. You'll have to refer to `get_pre_mlsag_hash()` for the exact computation.

Comment: Please update the question showing your code that created `msg`.

Comment: Also your version of MLSAG_Ver looks wrong to me (the loops). You should use the implementation in MiniNero MLSAG2.MLSAG_Ver.

Comment: @jtgrassie Thanks for the reply. What do you meant about "version" ?

Comment: Ok, I got it, the MLSAG_Ver() in MLSAG2.py.

Comment: I believe the MLSAG construction you wrote here is correct, although it's good to check it against a known implementation too.

Comment: "R1 = H(range_proofs) -> rctsig_prunable part." I'm not sure about the hex string you printed, but be sure to exclude the MLSAGs themselves from R1.

Comment: @koe, That is why I am so confused.. Because I have checked the MLSAG_Ver() in rctSigs.cpp several times.. The mistake I can imagine is the msg might be wrong.

Comment: `M1` is surely wrong as it should be hash of serialize_rctsig_base not `H(ss)`. That said, the values you have used for L, M and R look ok to me at a casual glance.

Comment: Also, your `pk` variable, where/how are you getting that data?

Comment: they are keys and commitments and I get them from explore manually.

Comment: @jtgrassie After taking a glance at serialize_rctsig_base(), I think it's not different from H(ss) which consists of {type, txnFee, ecdhInfo, outPk}.

Comment: "I get them from explore manually." <- They look wrong. The first key should be `b7abbe8630...`.

Comment: https://moneroblocks.info/search/886687fdd30ad46ef1f7c7c18402d82212b4ae1fd2cf6b4dfc549e46be7e22f6 shouldn't the first key be "8b5e1aedf..."?

Comment: Where are you seeing `8b5...`? https://xmrchain.net/tx/886687fdd30ad46ef1f7c7c18402d82212b4ae1fd2cf6b4dfc549e46be7e22f6/1 Shows the first ring member is `b7abbe...`.

Comment: It's weird, the results from xmrchain.net are different from moneroblocks.info.

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually get the ring members from moneroblocks.info (aside from their on-chain offsets/indices), how did you get your `pk` list?

Comment: @koe, I updated the pk list. I got previous ones from the "public key" of moneroblocks.info.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: I am sorry that it's still not working..

Comment: Can anyone help me to figure it out.

Comment: Have you looked at `get_pre_mlsag_hash()`?

Comment: Sure, and I think the processes are the same.

Comment: You seem to be missing the pseudo-output commitment, which needs to be added here for non-double-spendable-rows `L = MiniNero.addKeys(MiniNero.scalarmultBase(s[j][i]), MiniNero.scalarmultKey(pk[j][i] - pseudo-out-commitment, c)`. Or you could just update the `pk` list by subtracting the pseudoOut from each key `8c3a4f1bb2ffce27aaed405f84b70d8e04ee00774399f8efd28b5f19f1c3d333`.

Comment: Thanks! @koe You are right! I forgot to subtract pseudo output first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I originally thought the `pk` list included the pseudo out subtraction, since `MLSAG_gen()` takes as input a `pk` list that takes it into account. Hopefully this is enough for you to validate the signature :) please let us know how it goes

Comment: Thank you for reply @koe! It helps! I post an answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer and it works well.
The key point is that commitments should be subtracted by pseudoOuts first.

```
def MLSAG_Ver(msg, pk, n, m, m1, I, c0, s):
    c = c0
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        tohash = msg
        j = 0
        while j < m:
            if j == 1:
                pk[j][i] = MiniNero.subKeys(pk[j][i], pseu)

            tohash = tohash + pk[j][i]

            L = MiniNero.addKeys(MiniNero.scalarmultBase(s[j][i]), MiniNero.scalarmultKey(pk[j][i], c))
            tohash = tohash + L
            if j < m1:
                HP = MiniNero.hashToPointCN(pk[j][i])

                R = MiniNero.addKeys(MiniNero.scalarmultKey(HP, s[j][i]), MiniNero.scalarmultKey(I, c))
                tohash = tohash + R
            j = j+1
        c = MiniNero.sc_reduce_key(MiniNero.cn_fast_hash(tohash))
        i = i+1
    if c == c0:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")

msg = "25d83d029ac3eb919038b422326084e8aa4c7ff7db2f8891428d8bfe66c4abb5"
I = "3352ef16ca15e8cbc67cd1ddd66ae3dc8ea904ab19db9a29de287a5d948b152e"
pk = ["b7abbe863058eb4ed373feae10cfb372848bbe9511fdf4ffaaf69a512482d296",\
      "e926338f8a94751cd38a7c2c70a8b4c6b213eae28efb97cac686c7ef394be396",\
      "e92043567e7e0a6bd942bd765578c132174f496b21c78823a16be6e57e24aaeb",\
      "0377caa3292617487ba32d5a748750eebcca55ad8ac85e06bc772d32354f63af",\
      "a4792780889e5e55bffe1524dcf965d1908d198b5fe698ba7840869c0ecdd6df",\
      "7e684049c73626fa4704a43ace24dc3f1cd467bc22e22cbeba78659f36d14bc9",\
      "177ce3b8bb9c9e0475c6eb5500771cd828b36b1baab0e0eb46abc84ee811bc36",\
      "730e3a22f72b5c2724e822d92332ffd2c2803fba8ba50b5f46a645e719efdc50",\
      "7eb748799bfd30c60214f23ccc4e01b107b10c74435190410ce01aadd46b33e0",\
      "397dce6fadb5b8e37c80340f8a1eea01d2e794cf6faa806e160fa52f991a3bdb",\
      "757be6485a7b4370ac062389ae15b1b46d19b38dcadfde38436fb7c1ce056d59"],\
     ["fd2eca4d0506d9111359add3448be42ba6dbe28d732b5bc3a42cbd5613caaf13",\
      "71929d17d1863471663c7febdf3bace7cc9d366a9bfd1345c2cac43c35d68f8e",\
      "d450e032ba466dd0fadbe831ee5e91187711b37fa4f3c124629066b152ca599b",\
      "2aa4ac5a7d30e375af9153955b510dc3939dd8ceaf58992595356f663469fdac",\
      "7d0d91712e3ddc33c2fd92ce7216b319b3acb1b16aa8147976517e64b4158b67",\
      "4a0acfbe0a869589e66616681e93b9c311b6374d0873541295bc0a8437565376",\
      "e5990b5701085aec19c11d19edd8abf670ad1e53a77b4f0e82d142efdbfb28a0",\
      "75eb46a7b72b2f394d647d6c3b3de290f39238bf3034a381024d6b938e95ba97",\
      "4b4eb4b434f85102c728fe9134feec6cebfbefff881fa673feefc62d02527516",\
      "132cead5678f1902066ee4169de0d94b957360ec4d1e92340907c44a3d5440ad",\
      "cd334425475a8bc219a71c94c0c4b8e277cba0791fb545222dd5fe18e99e6712"]


s =  ["a3628fda5306c2c91986c05e0c939acb1c498c47276863c6b8b4b14381455d05",\
      "4f84565268d4cadd909f626bc85325d968364e5044de9decead91ecb824be60f",\
      "4cd282c891ac453902b0c7cf13a02bbcf328ff8ac4d2fafb20bbb0b67860db07",\
      "9a6e3526b4f28c448c830494e3f98cd0831351a1e5289a3f5c8363687d728206",\
      "733759bb10fc8e228b7ca8b257852418e31ba9b82488355f1fdb2abc9193f90e",\
      "1ece317df2d04b0c783740776362c2ba3c2d5a30fd63852b60d8d535cd92c701",\
      "405b4e3ce3e41be8e36d1d52b64d34a69d5f8eb0aff311202ee41c1cb3787508",\
      "aa2946443c0b2549da165eacd208d84e966e91db8cab27e5b07ec401580ed000",\
      "3ae2b18ce171311c711678d5829ebea65457b52ed7c6085c40782f0c9d8a380b",\
      "e93cf157e4d7c4505b249042a4ae7687354ffb815bf4d53717ea0678daee3407",\
      "b1c559a9140b090217905288ce8f16a961baed949102ad860afb9622259dd600"],\
     ["24a21c6d227540074830b7b4757fc086aba6d5c93babb913e37994f3fb6bb909",\
      "dd50708d2791d39a68caffb22fc99f5b663bf7df0f317913070e08150a0c830d",\
      "bf0d9a648c1c24530e1c9f1c3475b04a3f73de8ce8bc31904bd183da7fd1170e",\
      "13e3a1ced79931086e1682c446af97c58a2604e21df647869f1bb88919e5d602",\
      "df5816a00c64b3a1eced8ad30a1820b4785aaf6c10ff44dfbc71153ab2eb940e",\
      "7ae078de9bc0fe585c4d80ba8ebfea941c6a3a56105b4a6244737b9d0d0ced0e",\
      "a7d589bffc68febe0cbc59c56be34accc1c6847770480ca08a2826b611b9de02",\
      "bc09262d136f22a7c2af6c6a174283bb2f3c398838305f4934b3ea0a05083d0b",\
      "80e21b02139f40d5cc834ca3130a211141aca1a824ce073f26d82a72cafcae07",\
      "14550c61a8111d6a8e9def65195747d406c276e9f4f26b590e02b7b29278150d",\
      "35fc89f428f536dcd2264c9918f29bafa08d9f583b97593229ac8bf4befb7100"]

c0 = "0c7b9e033d4846dbee0d5bb9587d380ee0ae9f635e6376d37fa6f66c94ec3505"
pseu = "8c3a4f1bb2ffce27aaed405f84b70d8e04ee00774399f8efd28b5f19f1c3d333"

MLSAG_Ver(msg, pk, 11, 2, 1, I, c0, s)
```

Comment: You should update this to show how you're getting `msg` as that's a key part missing here (and what's used here is different to as shown in your question).