# How do I validate the signature of a Monero transaction manually?

Tags: ring-signatures

I'm trying to figure out how to validate the signature of a Monero transaction manually.

I've read this question: [How to verify MLSAG sign with a real transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12255/how-to-verify-mlsag-sign-with-a-real-transaction) and I am trying to recreate this example. It looks like the transaction is hashed to `25d83d029ac3eb919038b422326084e8aa4c7ff7db2f8891428d8bfe66c4abb5` and `MLSAG_Ver` can then be used to confirm that the signature in `rctsig_prunable/MGs` is valid. But I haven't been able to find any examples as to how this hash is calculated, so I'm hoping to get an example for both the transaction shown in that question (as well as the older RingCT type 2 transaction if possible).

What I've tried:

```
function sighash($l, $m, $r){
    $l = Sha3::hash(hex2bin($l), 256); //Keccak256 hash function
    $m = Sha3::hash(hex2bin($m), 256);
    $r = Sha3::hash(hex2bin($r), 256);
    return Sha3::hash(hex2bin($l.$m.$r), 256);
}

$l = '02000102000bda97ba08a9d6019dcd0194fa01ec458a0ce803bb01d202a401b2263352ef16ca15e8cbc67cd1ddd66ae3dc8ea904ab19db9a29de287a5d948b152e0200026ae6652253f1c77e93410f85bf0e495b306d2e5f4f2297ee4b4fc10fe871435c00028d703e7041838d747e5634b7ca6b990720c57f93e65f7f266b05e0dad6ca8b912c01ad79af52c10613be3b4a9a71bd2e8b92cdfa5fa2f548ba985fdd8385bb30947f020901d79d2e801fa7c27a';
$m = '049091a309fed5f2ae3250548eb60f5f3eb89676f186063e218c62711ff1991d89b3adb9824a26f3ee8e1c0e5ecbebf2951fb90b7d90716d8a6edc1bfdfba054fa5576d086056a7f3036956468e22148f0522fd6d4';
$r = '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';
echo sighash($l, $m, $r); //returns: 22967426bf12c748add7f2713532ac9f06f2d1341465d61b8b9a41135a75eebe
```

(Also, how difficult would it be to validate the bulletproof range proof? Also, I know the process of generating the transaction ID hash is similar to that of generating the hash to be signed, so how would that be done?)

Thank you!

Comment: The question you reference has a misleading answer and missing information. You need to refer to [get_pre_mlsag_hash](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/319b831e65437f1c8e5ff4b4cb9be03f091f6fc6/src/ringct/rctSigs.cpp#L573) and [serialize_rctsig_base](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/319b831e65437f1c8e5ff4b4cb9be03f091f6fc6/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L283) to see how the full message is obtained.